# Initial six calendar months of instrument currency

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, currency

FAR 61.57 states that to act as PIC under IFR or weather conditions lower than the minimums prescribed for VFR, you must have performed & logged, within the previous 6 calendar months prior to the month of the flight, 6 approaches, holding procedures & tasks, and intercepting & tracking courses in actual or simulated conditions.

If you failed to meet these requirements, you have 6 more months to log them under simulated conditions or in a training device/simulator.

After those additional 6 calendar months, you must get an Instrument Proficiency Check to re-establish IFR currency.

I understand all of the above.

My question is, where or how does the regulation say, that you are IFR current for those first 6 calendar months once you establish currency with an IPC, or the instrument checkride?

Comment: It's probably just one of those things that they neglected to spell out in the regs.

Comment: @quietflyer 61.57 (d) (1) says that you may "reestablish instrument currency" by completing an Instrument Proficiency Check.

Comment: @757toga -- ah I see-- likely worth mentioning specifically in answer

Comment: @quietflyer - good point.  Added to my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

FAR 61.57 (d) (1) says that you may "reestablish instrument currency" by completing an Instrument Proficiency Check.

Also, here is an FAA legal interpretation that says that the Instrument Proficiency Check "...starts the clock again for the purposes of 61.57(c)." (*see the last sentence of the second paragraph in the legal interpretation*)

[Legal Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2008/Wynne_2008_Legal_Interpretation.pdf)

Comment: But where is the clock defined as 6 calendar months for this period ?

Comment: @amirfl 61.57 (c) says you have to complete certain tasks within the 6 calendar months preceding the month of the flight to act as IFR pic. If you don't do those tasks (e.g. approaches,  etc) then you can't be **IFR** pic but you can complete those tasks under **VFR** until you've satisfied all the task requirements within the next 6 months. But if you fail to do that (12 months have now elapsed) 61.57 (d) requires an Instrument Proficiency Check to "reestablish instrument currency."

Comment: I understand that, but the FARs don’t seem to define the period following the checkride or the IPC as specifically 6 calendar months

Comment: @amirfl Well, I guess all I can say is that if the IPC "reestablishes currency" and "*starts the clock again for the purposes of 61.57 (c)*" and  61.57 (c) says you have to complete the required tasks within 6 calendar months to remain current for PIC IFR then it seems pretty specific that the period is 6 calendar months. Sorry,  but I can't offer any better of an explanation.

Comment: I do believe your answer is the best one. To be clear, I have no question as to the intent of this regulation. It is documented and explained in many places. However, I think the reg itself is poorly written and without outside interpretation is not clear cut.

Comment: I guess the regs also didn't mention the instrument checkride itself. Imagine a student that really spread out their instrument training and is not current on the day they pass instrument checkride and get the rating, do they need an IPC before they can fly IFR?